# defaultdict and tuples

Tags: python

I wanted to do the following:

```
d = defaultdict((int,float))
for z in range( lots_and_lots):
  d['operation one'] += (1,5.67)
  ...
  ...
  d['operation two'] += (1,4.56)
```

And then output the number of times each operation was called and the total of float value.

```
for k,v in d.items():
  print k, 'Called', v[0], 'times, total =', v[1]
```

But I don't know how to achieve this as not only can't you use a tuple as a parameter to defaultdict you can't add a tuple to a tuple and total the values in the tuple you just get extra values in your tuple.  i.e:

```
>>> x = (1,0)
>>> x+= (2,3)
>>> x
(1, 0, 2, 3)
```

and not

```
>>> x = (1,0)
>>> x+= (2,3)
>>> x
(3,3)
```

How can I get what I want?

Comment: Do you still think the selected answer is the best?

Comment: It worked great at the time.  Now?  Every solution should match the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assuming you have too many operations to simply store the list of values in each entry?

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for z in range(lots_and_lots):
  d['operation one'].append(5.67)
  ...
  ...
  d['operation two'].append(4.56)
for k,v in d.items():
  print k, 'Called', len(v), 'times, total =', sum(v)
```

---

One thing you could do is make a custom incrementor:

```
class Inc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.t = 0.0
    def __iadd__(self, f):
        self.i += 1
        self.t += f
        return self
```

and then

```
d = defaultdict(Inc)
for z in range(lots_and_lots):
  d['operation one'] += 5.67
  ...
  ...
  d['operation two'] += 4.56
for k,v in d.items():
  print k, 'Called', v.i, 'times, total =', v.t
```

Comment: The Inc class works like a charm.  Thanks David.  And thanks to everyone else who replied.

Answer (score 28):

You could do it with *[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)* to accumulate the results:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> d['operation_one'].update(ival=1, fval=5.67)
>>> d['operation_two'].update(ival=1, fval=4.56)
```

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer; it utilizes stdlib classes and requires no custom code to get working. Why not get whatever optimizations and additional features for free when you can?

Answer (score 22):

the argument to `defaultdict` must be a "callable" that returns a default value.   define your default dict like so:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: (0, 0.0))
```

The fact that `int` and `float` types can be called and return zero's is a convenience, but not in any way crucial to the way defaultdict works.

getting the `+=` to work is going to cause some trouble;  addition across tuples is the concatantion of the tuples, so you'll have to do it the long way:

```
left, right = d["key"]
d["key"] = (left + 2, right + 3)
```

**Edit:**  if you just *must* use +=, you can do so, so long as you have a collection type that has the desired operations.  [fileoffset suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483930/65696) using a `numpy` array type, and that's probably a nice idea, but you can get a close approximation just by subclassing `tuple` and overriding the operators you need:  Here's a rough sketch of one:

```
class vector(tuple):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(l+r for l, r in zip(self, other))
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return type(self)(l-r for l, r in zip(self, other))
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return type(self)(l+r for l, r in zip(self, other))
    def __lsub__(self, other):
        return type(self)(r-l for l, r in zip(self, other))

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda:vector((0, 0.0)))
for k in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        d[k] += (j, j+k)

print d
```

we don't need (or want) to actually overload the `+=` operator itself (spelled `__iadd__`) because `tuple` is immutable.  Python will correctly replace the old value with new if you supply addition.

Answer (score 1):

If you use numpy array's you can get the desired output:

[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5)

Answer (score 1):

Write a class that you can pass into `defaultdict` that accumulates values as you pass them in:

```
class Tracker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = None
        self.count = 0

    def __iadd__(self, newvalues):
        self.count += 1
        if self.values is None:
            self.values = newvalues
        else:
            self.values = [(old + new) for old, new in zip(self.values, newvalues)]
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tracker(%s, %d)>' % (self.values, self.count)
```

That's a drop-in replacement for `(int, float)` in your original post. Change your output loop to print the instance attributes like so:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print k, 'Called', v.count, 'times, total =', v.values
```

...and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = (1,0)
b = (2,3)

res = tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(a,b)
```

e.g.

```
d = defaultdict((int,float))
for z in range( lots_and_lots):
  d['operation one'] = tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(d['operation one'], (1,5.67))
  ...
  ...
```